# how to implement core product API in cs-cart addon controller ?

Tags: cs-cart

I am creating an cs-cart Addon for pulling all inventory data via addon.

I tried to implement for product API implementation in custom Addon controller to show list of all products with its all product information , but unfortunately i am unable to implement API in my custom Addon controller in cs cart ?

Please can you provide help on how to implement core API of cs-cart in addon controller.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a CS-Cart add-on you have access to all core functions. For product search, you can use `fn_get_products($params, $items_per_page, $lang_code)` function. For more information, you should check the function itself in `/app/functions/fn_catalog.php` around line 6000 (the line depends on your actual version of CS-Cart).

You can use these parameters in the `$params` array to fine-tune your results:

```
$default_params = array (
        'area' => AREA,
        'use_caching' => true,
        'extend' => array('product_name', 'prices', 'categories'),
        'custom_extend' => array(),
        'pname' => '',
        'pshort' => '',
        'pfull' => '',
        'pkeywords' => '',
        'feature' => array(),
        'type' => 'simple',
        'page' => 1,
        'action' => '',
        'filter_variants' => array(),
        'features_hash' => '',
        'limit' => 0,
        'bid' => 0,
        'match' => '',
        'tracking' => array(),
        'get_frontend_urls' => false,
        'items_per_page' => $items_per_page,
        'apply_disabled_filters' => ''
    );
```

Comment: Thank you, @ISTI , this helped me alot.